# 1em not really 1em? My text is too big for my div

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some CSS for a project, and came across this very weird occurrence. As you can see from the screenshot:

[image: picture]

My text actually comes out of his div, and is not sitting on the baseline of the div.

What could be causing this?

I have also included the relevant CSS which might come in handy.

```
element.style {
}
#page-title {
color: #84ae2d;
font-family: 'futurama';
font-size: 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1em;
height: 1em;
}
.page__title, .node__title, .block__title, .comments__title, .comments__form-title, .comment__title {
margin: 0;
}
h1 {
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 1.5em;
margin-top: 0.75em;
margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
user agent stylesheeth1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
}
Inherited from div#content.column
#header, #content, #navigation, .region-sidebar-first, .region-sidebar-second, #footer {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
word-wrap: break-word;
_display: inline;
_overflow: hidden;
_overflow-y: visible;
}
Inherited from html.js
html {
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, "DejaVu Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 75%;
font-size: 87.5%;
font-size: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: can you create fiddle or u can provide screen shot of your page with that inspect of that element

Comment: can you post this page somewhere live so we can see it in action. (*to check if it is an issue with the font*)

Comment: @yugi You can find screen shot [here](http://i.imgur.com/nQCM4nz.png)

Comment: @Neglexis yugi asked fiddle not screen shot

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli It seems to be an issue with the font like you suggested. I tried another font, and now it fits fine. Is there a way to fix the font? Or should I just revert to margins?

Comment: You could adjust the line-height and height for that element until it will contain its text..

Answer (score 1):

try this

Replace you `h1` with this

```
h1 {
font-size: 1.5em;
line-height: 1.5em;
margin-top: 0.75em;
margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
```

Your line-height is 1.5em but font size is 2em

You should have your font-size, line-height should be same like this `font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;`

Comment: these are overridden by the `#page-title` rule

Comment: My font size is actually 40px, line 6 of my CSS.

Comment: @Neglexis your font size is 40px but your `<h1>` tag font size is 1.5em **have you tried above code**

Comment: Yes, I have tried the code. But the font size of my <h1> gets overridden by my #page-title markup, like @GabyakaG.Petrioli said.

Comment: then you must post a **live demo**